# How to pass custom text in mappers in Feeds JSONPath Parser module in Drupal7

Tags: json, drupal-7, jsonpath, drupal-feeds

I'm just trying to fetch the instagram images from api to drupal using Feeds JSONPath Parser module https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_jsonpath_parser, i implemented the setup and imported the images but i want to pass the custom text in mappers. just like this question below https://www.drupal.org/node/2194301.

TIA,
Raj